# Spring Boot - Spring Data - Jersey - No results of repositories during JUnit integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

struggling long time with that issue and I have the weird feeling it has something to do on how I am setting my @Transactional annotation.

So what do I want to do?

1. I am preparing some data and save them with the available repositories in the database.

This can be found here in my FormTest class in the **prepareExampleApplication** method

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class FormTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationRepository applicationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AppActionRepository appActionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private FormRepository formRepository;

    @Autowired
    private FormElementRepository formElementRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SectionRepository sectionRepository;

    private Application application;
    private InputField refInputField;
    private Select refSelectBox;

    @Before
    public void prepareExampleApplication() {

        Form form = formRepository.save(ModelFactory.getForm("Project"));

        Application application = ModelFactory.getApplication("Example", form);

        this.application = applicationRepository.save(application);

        Role role = new Role();
        role.setRoleName("ADMIN");
        role.setApp(application);

        role = roleRepository.save(role);

        Section section = ModelFactory.getSection(form, null, null);

        section = formElementRepository.save(section);

        InputField inputField = ModelFactory.getInputField(form, section, section);

        refInputField = formElementRepository.save(inputField);
        //once again. Just for my own eyes to see if it is there
        Iterable<Form> all = formRepository.findAll();

       // lot more stuff


    }


    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testUserInput() {

        // first create a new container to give inouts

        Long id = this.application.getEntity().getId();
        // for the sake of debugging I am using the formRepo to really SEARCH for the persisted form AND IT IS THERE!!!
        Form byId = formRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);

        URI uri = this.restTemplate.postForLocation("/api/form/" + id + "/forminstance", null);
        long containerId = TestHelper.extractId(uri);


    }
}
```

2. The next thing I am doing having this data is to use the restTemplate and dispatch a post request to a REST service. You can find the POST call in the test method. For debugging reasons - and to see that the repo is working - I am REALLY using the repository to get the id of the form instead of using the class field that had been filled with the preparation method. AND the form will be returned!!
3. Within my rest service I am using the formRepository once again, looking for the entity I have found before in the test class. But THIS TIME the repository does not return anything. Only null. I have tried SO MANY different things with setting @Transactional on different locations, but whatever I do the formRepository within the REST service does only give me back 0 entites and a null. Here is the REST service

   ```
   @Service
   @Api("FormService")
   @Path("/form")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public class FormService {

       @Autowired
       private FormInstanceRepository formInstanceRepository;

       @Autowired
       private FormRepository formRepository;

       @Autowired
       private FormElementRepository formElementRepository;

       @Autowired
       private UserInputRepository userInputRepository;

       @POST
       @Path("{id}/forminstance")
       @Transactional
       public Response createFormInstance(@Context UriInfo info, @PathParam("id") long formId) {
           // returns ALWAYS 0 elements
           Iterable<Form> all = formRepository.findAll(); 
           // returns always null       
           Form form = formRepository.findById(formId).orElse(null);

           FormInstance formInstance = new FormInstance();
           formInstance.setForm(form);
           FormInstance save = formInstanceRepository.save(formInstance);

           UriBuilder builder = info.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
           builder.path(Long.toString(save.getId()));

           return Response.created(builder.build()).build();

       }
   ```

   IF you know the answer I am really interested in the explanation to understand my error. I am using an in-memory H2 db for the tests.

Adding the Form entity and FormRepository, too

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    public class Form {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        private String name;

    }
```

-

```
    public interface FormRepository extends CrudRepository<Form, Long> {
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: The repository won't return anything because you are testing the controller and the service layer interaction. The test above is valid because you are testing the controller and the service layers in isolation. You need a different test for service and repository.

Comment: You don't need the repositories in the `FormTest`.

Comment: Hi @alltej 
I get your comment, I should test each component independently, but what possibilities do I have to achieve what I try? Is this such an uncommon case to test one "roundtrip" with having the repos return "real data"?

Comment: you won't be able to achieve that with `@SpringBootTest` annotation. When testing with this annotation, you are testing the endpoint http response. With that, your app is loaded live to some extent (thus the random port parameter but not the embedded container - tomcat by default). To achieve the test you are looking for, is to use the `@WebMvcTest` annotation which is really unit-testing the controller. You can find examples of those.